# Create an object type out of multiple types

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to figure out how to create an object-based type, which keys are fixed and map to a specific property of a type. The values should use the type which corresponds to the the property.

Consider the following types:

```js
interface CooldownError {
  message: 'cooldown'
  minutes: Number
}

interface AbortError {
  message: 'error'
  description: string
}
```

Based on the `message` property, I want a type which has the following signature:

```js
type ErrorCollection = {
    cooldown: (e: CooldownError) => void;
    error: (e: AbortError) => void;
}
```

What I tried so far:

```js
type GQLErrors = CooldownError | AbortError;
type ErrorCollection = { [key in GQLErrors['message']]: (e: GQLErrors) => void };
```

While this works for the keys, all values are set to the union. I didn't find a way to deconstruct the union somehow. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're already committed to having a union type like `GQLErrors` around (and you kind of need to do that, since otherwise there's no way to know what to iterate), you can tweak your definition of `ErrorCollection` like this:

```
type ErrorCollection = {
  [K in GQLErrors['message']]: (e: Extract<GQLErrors, { message: K }>) => void
};
```

Here we're using the built-in utility type [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) which takes a union type `T` and returns the union of only those members of `T` which match `U`.  So `Extract<GQLErrors, { message: K }>` will become `CooldownError` when `K` is `"cooldown"`, and `AbortError` when `K` is `"error"`.  You can verify that the compiler sees `ErrorCollection` as:

```
/*
type ErrorCollection = {
    cooldown: (e: CooldownError) => void;
    error: (e: AbortError) => void;
}
*/
```

which is what you wanted.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHt0BsAm6DuIAolFOlMgN4BQyyAthAM5NwDmEAXMgOQKa4CIHrQagArpCbcAcuPoAjaNQC+1aqEixEKAIILyYEmQo06jFuy69oJkXRzMEUYAAcwwdCG5MwLkGyq6mAAnq4oAOIAigAyxuRMyAC8aAJ4hPEUAD7I+oaZANzBYSiZGFhYEAgeXslUogDaANLIoMjRcaQJDTwWrBw8ALqD3AAU1kQAHn6IYAA8HZlMADRUDMz91i0qAHwAlMk7yABu6MA4qkXUAPQAVNSh4chl2JXVniB1ZnTI-Njp3mQ424GH+QkyBySR1O5yKP2QtnIY2seSgRi6UEh0LOOCKalu1yAA)

Comment: Thanks! Extract<T, U> was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could use an intermediate interface, like so:

```
interface CooldownError {
  message: 'cooldown'
  minutes: Number
}

interface AbortError {
  message: 'abort' // changed from 'error'
  description: string
}

interface Intermediate {
  cooldown:  CooldownError
  abort: AbortError
}

type ErrorCollection = {[K in keyof Intermediate]: (e: Intermediate[K]) => void}
```

note you're responsible of keeping the `Intermidate` interface keys the same as the errors' `message` key.